VBA and Combobox values
I have a form with a combo box, and I would like the corresponding values related to the selected ID from the combo box to display in text boxes. The issue is that the text boxes only display the values from the last added ID. Here is my code, and thank you in advance for your help.
    lastrow = wscontact.Cells(wscontact.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow + 1
        If Val(Me.txtindexcontact) = Val(wscontact.Cells(i, 12).Value) Then
            If Trim(UCase(cbContact.Value)) = Trim(UCase(wscontact.Cells(i, 3).Value)) & " " & Trim(UCase(wscontact.Cells(i, 4).Value)) Then
                MsgBox "find"
                FrmVisites.txtfirstname = wscontact.Cells(i, 3).Value
                FrmVisites.txtlastname = wscontact.Cells(i, 4).Value
                FrmVisites.txtposition = wscontact.Cells(i, 5).Value
                FrmVisites.txtphone1 = wscontact.Cells(i, 6).Value
                FrmVisites.txtextension = wscontact.Cells(i, 7).Value
                FrmVisites.txtemail = wscontact.Cells(i, 8).Value
                FrmVisites.txtcellnumber = wscontact.Cells(i, 9).Value
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i


What is the value of Me.txtindexcontact? If  Me.txtindexcontact = wscontact.Cells(lastrow + 1, 12).Value then you would only get the last values from the wscontact combo box.

thanks a lot, your message was very helpful.

If Me.txtindexcontact = wscontact.Cells(lastrow + 1, 12).Value then you would only get the last values from the wscontact combo box.
